# Fixing undefined shader nodes

Tags: scripting, node-editor, shaders

[image: undefined mix RGB]I am using blender 3.0.0 and i have many shader trees on objects with undefined mix RGB nodes, is there a script or any other way to revers to the original nodes state on multiply objects?

Comment: Suggestion.  Please include a screen capture of some relevant Blender UI.  Please try to edit your writing to be more clear.

Comment: The word [undefined] seems to be spelled in two different ways in your writing.  The title seems incorrect.

Comment: Are you trying to load files made in a much earlier version of blender (pre-2.83)?

Comment: You're probably loading a .blend from a newer version of Blender. Easiest thing to do is just update your Blender. You could try writing a script to guess what the node should be from the input/output socket names but I don't think you can get what eg. the mode on Mix nodes should be. But really, just update Blender.

Comment: @Christopher Bennett,Thanks, This is a file i have opened before in version 3.0 and never had this problem. I am not vey good at scripting.

Comment: @scurest,Thanks, I have already tried all stable versions all the same problem.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger, Thanks spelling corrected.

Comment: @digitvisions Did you try the latest alpha?

Comment: @scurest, this is a production project file the alpha is not a stable version.